# logic, Statement manipulation with Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

$x,y$ are rational numbers

$$\forall x((x^2 \geq 0) ∨ \neg \exists y( y^2 = -6 ))$$

If I manipulate the above statement the following way, are they equivalent?

$$\forall x\neg \exists y((x^2 ≥ 0) ∨ ( y^2 = -6 ))$$

More generally:

$$\forall x(P(x) \% \neg \exists y Q(y)) := \forall x \neg \exists y(P(x) \% Q(y)),$$

where $P,Q$ are predicates and $\%$ is some logical connective.

Since I've been taught that the range of a quantifier is the inside of the brackets it shouldn't matter. However, I'm afraid that once I use De Morgan for both cases I end up with logically different statements.

Comment: This may be helpful https://www.math.uci.edu/~xiangwen/pdf/LaTeX-Math-Symbols.pdf

Comment: @CharlieChang Thank your very much! I just saved it! do I just type it as it is like \sum? or should I do something beforehand

Comment: Type \sum in between dollars to get $\sum$

Comment: @VoiletFlame $\sum$ ok thanks your very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $x,y$ are rational numbers
>
> $$\forall x((x^2 \geq 0) ∨ \neg \exists y( y^2 = -6 ))\tag1$$
>
> If I manipulate the above statement the following way, are they
> equivalent?
>
> $$\forall x\neg \exists y((x^2 ≥ 0) ∨ ( y^2 = -6 ))\tag2$$

No, unfortunately. $(1)$ is logically equivalent to $$\forall x\;((x^2 \geq 0) ∨ \forall y( y^2 \ne -6 )),$$ which is logically equivalent to $$\forall x\forall y\;((x^2 \geq 0) ∨ ( y^2 \ne -6 )).$$

On the other hand, $(2)$ is logically equivalent to $$\forall x\forall y\;((x^2 < 0) ∧ ( y^2 \ne -6 )).$$

> More generally:
>
> $$\forall x(P(x) \% \neg \exists y Q(y)) := \forall x \neg \exists y(P(x) \% Q(y)),$$

Correction: $$\forall x(P(x) \:\%\: \neg \exists y Q(y)) \equiv \forall x  \;(P(x) \:\%\: \forall y ¬Q(y)).$$

The correct way to pull $\forall y$ to the front of the sentence depends on what connective $\%$ is. [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) contains more information.

Comment: Very well! thank your very much this helps so much!!!! The link you added is very helpful as well!!

Comment: ok thanks! If you don't mind I would like ask one more question. The proposition "in the open interval (0,1) a largest number does not exist" 
I would formalize as follows: $ \forall x(((x>0) \wedge (x<1)) \to \exists y((y>x) \wedge (y<1)))$ . However I need to decide if the following: $ \forall x \exists y((x>0) \wedge (x<1) \wedge (x<y) \wedge (y<1)) $ corresponds to the verbal proposition.
My problem is that the 2nd logical proposition sounds correct when I translate it however I can't manipulate it to the 1st proposition (which I know for sure is correct) using the Prenex tools.

Comment: Your first formalisation is correct; its Prenex form is $\forall x \exists y\;(((x>0) \wedge (x<1)) \to ((x<y) \wedge (y<1))).$ We are able to pull $\exists y$ to the front because $y$ is not free in the antecedent.

Comment: ∀x∃y((x>0)∧(x<1)∧(x<y)∧(y<1)) so this one is not correct? 
although it translates: " for every x there exists y such that  0<x<1 and x<y<1" which arguably sounds true...

Comment: Sorry for the insecurity, so just to make sure the 2nd formalization doesn't match the verbal proposition "in the open interval (0,1) a largest number does not exist" correct?

Comment: No it doesn't. Second is a stronger claim than First. Second claims that whatever $x$ is, we can find some $y$ such that $x\in(0,1),\;y<1\;$ and $x<y;$ the counterexample $x=100$ clearly shows that Second is false. Welcome to this site!

Comment: Wait Im confused you agreed with me saying it doesn't and said it actually is and it is a stronger claim? Sorry Im a bit lost and thank you!

Comment: Maybe my assumption that there is only one way to formalize this verbal proposition and all other ways must be logically equivalent to this way, is false and that’s what misleading me?

Comment: 1. Second implies First,  but Second $\not\equiv$ First.  2. $x<3$ and $x<8$ aren't equivalent claims: the former is stronger than the latter.  Makes sense? -)

Comment: Yeah it makes sense thanks! I just want to make sure that the 2nd (the one with the “AND’s”) is a possible  formalization of the verbal proposition? It is right?

Comment: Second is stronger than First, which is a formalisation of That Verbal Sentence. Therefore, That Verbal Sentence cannot be a formalisation of Second. (Formalising a verbal sentence neither strengthens nor weakens its meaning.)

Comment: Haha perfectly clear thanks a lot! your patience and explanation are not taken as granted! Very much appreciated!